# Persisting large data

Tags: android

I'm getting a lot of data in my Activity and I need to save it on configuration change and to reuse it to reduce network requests. I'm thinking about shared preferences or putting data into Bundle. Shared preferences seems like more expensive operation, but I'm not sure. Please advice what approach is better to take.

Can it be also possible to save data in separate thread, will not it be stopped if activity destroyed?

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about?

Comment: *"will not it be stopped if activity destroyed?"* The thread will be stopped and destroyed. Have you considered using a `Service`? Also a DB seems more appropriate for large data than any kind of file.

Comment: This is just a big collection, created by parsing json which I get from a server.

Comment: @m0skit0 How would a thread be stopped and destroyed with the Activity? It will rather create memory leak if it is an anonymous class or gets anonymous Runnable-based class.

Comment: @m0skit0 A `Thread` won't be stopped/destroyed just because an `Activity` is stopped/destroyed. Threads have their own lifecycle which is separate from other Android components. Thread would only go away if it runs to completion or if Android kills off the process.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my mistake. The thread would be stopped and killed in case the **process** is destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only concerned about persisting the data through a configuration change, then you don't need to persist it anywhere. You can just put a reference to the data in a static variable. It will be available to all activities.

Be aware, however, that if your App goes to the background and Android kills off the process, then the data would be lost. If you need to deal with that case then you may be better off putting the data in a database. Shared Preferences is OK for simple data (primitives, Strings, etc.) but not for structured data (complex objects, lists, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the same thread you use to retrieve data from the server and store it in DB. If you don't have one - create it.

I'd suggest not doing threading inside `Activity`, because of lifecycle issues. Extend `Application` and use `Activity.getApplication`.